# How can I use filtered dropbox for my external database values

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django to make a frontend for my python project where I need to create a credential form to make a connection with the database tool e.q. PostgreSQL that I have created. Now I want a dropdown to list all the databases available in my PostgreSQL and then another dropdown to list all schemas present in the selected database in the first dropdown and then another dropdown for tables present in the selected schema using the second dropdown.

I have checked many videos for this but all are showing with the models. But I want these dropdown values from an external database not from models.

I have tried to create a python file to create a form inside my Django app where I am using forms.ChoiceField to list the database values. But unable to get the selected value for of the dropdown. So that I can query the schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example, I have created a project `t_project` and an app `t_app`.
I have used `psycopg2` library to explore the database with raw cursor (no Django wrapper).
I have manually set the field.choices with the values I got from psycopg.

---

```
# /t_project/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    't_app.apps.TAppConfig',
]
```

---

```
# /t_project/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from t_app import views as t_app_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', t_app_views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('<str:database>/', t_app_views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('<str:database>/<str:schema>/', t_app_views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

---

```
# /t_app/templates/t_app/test.html

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

---

```
# /t_app/views.py

import psycopg2
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic


class DBForm(forms.Form):
    database = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['database'].choices = self._get_databases()

    def _get_databases(self):
        conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='postgres_pass'"
        with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute('SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = FALSE')
            return [(d, d) for d, in cursor.fetchall()]


class SchemaForm(DBForm):
    schema = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, database, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['database'].initial = database
        self.fields['schema'].choices = self._get_schemas(database)

    def _get_schemas(self, database):
        # TODO Do NOT forget to escape "database" here to prevent injections
        conn_string = f"host='localhost' dbname='{database}' user='postgres' password='postgres_pass'"
        with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute('SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata')
            return [(s, s) for s, in cursor.fetchall()]


class TableForm(SchemaForm):
    table = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, database, schema, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(database, *args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['schema'].initial = schema
        self.fields['table'].choices = self._get_tables(database, schema)

    def _get_tables(self, database, schema):
        # TODO Do NOT forget to escape "database" here to prevent injections
        conn_string = f"host='localhost' dbname='{database}' user='postgres' password='postgres_pass'"
        with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute('SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = %s', (schema,))
            return [(t, t) for t, in cursor.fetchall()]


class TestView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 't_app/test.html'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()

        database = self.kwargs.get('database')
        schema = self.kwargs.get('schema')
        if schema:
            return TableForm(database=database, schema=schema, **kwargs)
        if database:
            return SchemaForm(database=database, **kwargs)
        return DBForm(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        database = form.cleaned_data.get('database')
        schema = form.cleaned_data.get('schema')
        table = form.cleaned_data.get('table')
        if table:
            print('Exit is here')
        if schema:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test', kwargs={'schema': schema, 'database': database}))
        if database:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test', kwargs={'database': database}))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test'))
```

Comment: Thanks @mistiru for sharing. It is working till schema. it gives me error "field required" when I select schema. I have tried to print schema inside TestView Class and is showing me "None".

Comment: @JaswantSingh Ok it was because of the "disabled" attribute (I put in my post after having tested), that prevent the form from sending the value. I edited my post, and now it works ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mistiru for help. It is working now. But I have another question, Can we do it without a submit button?

Comment: Yes, we can do everything you want ^^ Without a submit button, you can attach a "onchange" listener to the field (with javascript, just in case ;) ), and those listener will submit the form, or you can do it with ajax, or really, whatever you want ^^ I just provided a minimal example (that's why I used inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. **return all databases**

```
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database="test",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="5432"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

# first: get all databases
cursor.execute(
    """
    SELECT datname
    FROM pg_database
    WHERE datistemplate = false;
    """
)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
dbs = [row[0] for row in rows]

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

The front end renders dropdown, then query all the schemas with the selected database.

2. **return all schemas**

```
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database="test",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="5432"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
# second: get all schemas
# DB is the database selected in the previous step
cursor.execute(
    """
    SELECT schema_name
    FROM information_schema.schemata
    WHERE catalog_name = 'DB';
    """
)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

schemes = [row[0] for row in rows]
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Same as the previous one, Then use the selected schema and database to query all the tables

3. **return all tables**

```
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database="test",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="5432"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
# third: get all tables
# SCHEMA is the schema selected in the previous step
cursor.execute(
    """
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'SCHEMA'
        AND table_catalog = 'DB';
    """
)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

tables = [row[0] for row in rows]

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

You can embed the above code into your django code to do the next thing.

Comment: I already wrote a python code to get all these. I am not able to embed it to django frontend